# jQuery unobtrusive form

Tags: jquery

In order to validate a form like:

```
<input type="text" name="trueExplain" />
<input type="text" name="true1" />
<input type="text" name="true2" />
<input type="text" name="true3" />
<input type="text" name="true4" />
<input type="text" name="true5" />
```

in order to validate fields before submit, I want to add an id for each input element:

```
<input type="text" name="true1" />
```

becomes:

```
<input id="true1" type="text" name="true1" />
```

Then, for each input element, I want to add a label:

```
<input type="text" name="trueExplain" />
<input type="text" name="true1" />
etc
```

becomes:

```
<label for="trueExplain"></label>
<input id="trueExplain" type="text" name="trueExplain" />
<label for="true1"></label>
<input id="true1" type="text" name="true1" />
etc
```

I need some guidance both in design and implementation with jQuery.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate the need for jQuery. An HTML form should always have labels.

Comment: Are labels for displaying some kind of error message?

Comment: I don't think they should be, semantic-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this with jQuery you could use something like for IDs:

```
$('input[type=text][name^=true"]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

For labels something like that:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    var label = $(document.createElement('label'));
    label.attr('for', $(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).before(label);
});
```

But personally I would rather set those IDs and labels in HTML.